# Is no defined ordering between partial structs always a problem?

Tags: c#, .net-core

When attempting to use an internal partial struct to split a larger (now partial) class up into smaller files of related code, the compiler warns me with [CS0282](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0282?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0282)), no defined ordering between fields of a partial struct.

Editor.Interface.cs:

```cs
internal partial struct EditorState
{
    public int SomeOtherValue;
}
```

Editor.Logic.cs:

```cs
internal partial struct EditorState
{
    public int SomeValue;
}
```

I was expecting a partial struct declared across classes, especially an internal one, to not warn, like a partial class wouldn't. In my case, the struct is a state struct for a UI that can be accessed between the interface part, and the logic part of the class. I don't forsee the lack of defined ordering being a problem for me, as nothing external accesses the struct.

For now, I've switched the struct to a partial class which does not warn, but searching around, there isn't much about *why* this compiler warning exists to begin with.

Comment: It exists because a major use case for structs is interop with unmanaged code (and other shenanigans with direct memory access in managed code) that require a defined order and a deterministic layout (whether the struct is `public` is largely immaterial to that). This is not applicable to classes, as you cannot rely on their in-memory layout anyway, which is why a warning is not necessary there. It's safe to suppress the warning if you're not using the structs in situations where direct memory access is necessary and the struct is only there to avoid heap allocation.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think you'd get the same warning if you applied the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` attribute to a partial class.

Comment: @Ashleigh: Do you still get the warning if you apply the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]` attribute to the struct?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: yeah, and confusingly the warning will still talk about a "struct" rather than a class, since classes with explicit layout are relatively rare (as the layout there *only* applies for interop purposes, unlike structs). And `LayoutKind.Auto` for structs indeed suppresses the warning and is a clearer expression of intent than suppressing the warning.

Comment: In general, I would expect warnings to not *always* indicate a problem, if that was the case I would expect an *error*.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Can confirm, as Jeroen mentioned, `LayoutKind.Auto` does supress the warning and correctly expresses the intent of the struct's layout not mattering too.